# Jsp + JS + DBLookup + inside condition , solution?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsp-tags

Here I have 2 tags queries, I want to call them in JSP inside a Text List with condition if based on previous selected item from list also, here is my code :
First the JS function :

```
<script language="javascript">


    var basevalue;
    function checkoutlet(id)
{
    basevalue= document.getElementsById(id).value;
    return basevalue;
}




</script>
```

and here is the JSP part :

```
<tr>
                <td class="txtMF">Base<span class="txtnbmed"><span class="txtredsmall">*</span></span></td>
                <td class="txtnbmed" Id="base">
                            <html:select property="spotterBase">
                            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                            <dblookup:DBLookupTagVer2 lookUpName="common.spotter.base" />
                            </html:select>
                        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="txtMF">Outlet Code</td>
                <td class="txtnbmed">
                            <html:select property="spotterOutlet" onchange="checkoutlet('<%=base%>');">

                            <option value="">-- Select --</option>

                            <script language="javascript">
                             if (basevalue.equals("Branch")){ 
                            </script>

                            <dblookup:DBLookupTagVer2 lookUpName="common.spotter.outletb" />

                            <script language="javascript">
                             } else if (basevalue.equals("Dealer")){ 
                            </script> 

                            <dblookup:DBLookupTagVer2 lookUpName="common.spotter.outletd" />
                             <script language="javascript"> } </script> 
                            </html:select>
                        </td>
            </tr>
```

Sorry the code is a bit messy ! I need some help to fix that, thanks by advance :)

Comment: More clarification; when I choose an "base" item, the list  of outlet takes effect directly and calls the suitable query (lookupName), so in my case If the base is "Branch", it will call the lookUpName="common.spotter.outletb", else if "Dealer" the lookUpName="common.spotter.outletd" will be called, else if the base is other no query will be callet so by result the outlet code list will be empty (no options), this is the senario that i want ! I hope some one can help me , it's an emergency ! Thank you

Comment: so what is currently output of Outlet Code?

Comment: The currently output of outlet select list is the result of both queries combined together !! and this output is same and doesn't change if I choose an other "base" option !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution for who is interested :

First in JS part :

```
function checkoutlet()
{
document.forms[0].action = "populate_spotter_instant.do";
document.forms[0].submit();

}
```

populate_spotter_instant is a service which helps to apply chages instantle it means just you write in the form and the struts form will save the new values, In Service file here is the service, its logic is to take the values from the current form and save then in the object, something similar to this :

```
private ActionForward doPopulateSpotterInstant(
        ActionMapping mapping,
        SpotterSelectForm spotterForm,
        SessionData sessionData)
        throws Exception
    {
    log.debug("doPopulateSpotterInstant | Begin ");

    SpotterRequestValueObject requestVo = new SpotterRequestValueObject();

    String branchCode2 = getBranchCode(sessionData);
    log.debug("doPopulateSpotterInstant | branchCode:" + branchCode2);

    requestVo.setBranchCode(branchCode2);


    String spotterCode = spotterForm.getSpotterCode();
    log.debug("doPopulateSpotterInstant | spotterCode:" + spotterCode);

    String companyCode = spotterForm.getCompanyCode();
    log.debug("doPopulateSpotterInstant | companyCode:" + companyCode);

    String createdBy = getUserID(sessionData);
    log.debug("doPopulateSpotterInstant | createdBy:" + createdBy);

    Timestamp createTimestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    log.debug("doPopulateSpotterInstant | createdTM:" + createTimestamp);

    requestVo.setSpotterCode(spotterCode);

    Gspotter gSpotter = new Gspotter();
    GspotterPK pk = new GspotterPK();
    pk.setSpCode(spotterCode);
    pk.setComp_code(companyCode);
    gSpotter.setComp_id(pk);
    gSpotter.setName(spotterForm.getSpotterName());
    gSpotter.setSpId(spotterForm.getSpotterId());
    gSpotter.setBr_code(branchCode2);
    gSpotter.setType(spotterForm.getSpotterType());
    gSpotter.setBase(spotterForm.getSpotterBase());
    gSpotter.setOutlet(spotterForm.getSpotterOutlet());
    gSpotter.setDesignation(spotterForm.getDesignation());
    gSpotter.setContact_no(spotterForm.getSpotterContactNo());
    gSpotter.setAddr1(spotterForm.getSpotterAddress1());
    gSpotter.setAddr2(spotterForm.getSpotterAddress2());
    gSpotter.setAddr3(spotterForm.getSpotterAddress3());
    gSpotter.setAddr4(spotterForm.getSpotterAddress4());
    gSpotter.setPostcode(spotterForm.getSpotterPostCode());
    gSpotter.setCreatedBy(createdBy);
    gSpotter.setCreateTimestamp(createTimestamp);

    requestVo.setSpotterObj(gSpotter);


    log.debug("doPopulateSpotterInstant | End ");
    return mapping.getInputForward();
    }
```

OK, NOW IN JSP PART :

```
<tr>
                <td class="txtMF">Base<span class="txtnbmed"><span class="txtredsmall">*</span></span></td>
                <td class="txtnbmed" id="base">
                            <html:select property="spotterBase" onchange="javascript:checkoutlet();">
                            <option value="">-- Select --</option>
                            <dblookup:DBLookupTagVer2 lookUpName="common.spotter.base" />
                            </html:select>
                        </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="txtMF">Outlet Code</td>
                <td class="txtnbmed">
                <%

                SpotterSelectForm form = (SpotterSelectForm)request.getAttribute("SpotterSelectForm");

                if(form.getSpotterBase() == null){
                 %>         <html:select property="spotterOutlet" disabled="true">

                            <option value="">-- Select --</option>                              
                            <dblookup:DBLookupTagVer2 lookUpName="common.spotter.outletd" >

                            </dblookup:DBLookupTagVer2>

                            </html:select>

                <%
                }else if(form.getSpotterBase() == 'B'){
                %>
                <html:select property="spotterOutlet">

                            <option value="">-- Select --</option>                              
                            <dblookup:DBLookupTagVer2 lookUpName="common.spotter.outletb" >

                            </dblookup:DBLookupTagVer2>

                            </html:select>
                <%
                }else if(form.getSpotterBase() == 'D'){
                 %>

                            <html:select property="spotterOutlet" >

                            <option value="">-- Select --</option>                              
                            <dblookup:DBLookupTagVer2 lookUpName="common.spotter.outletd" >

                            </dblookup:DBLookupTagVer2>

                            </html:select>


                <%
                }else {
                 %>         <html:select property="spotterOutlet" disabled="true">

                            <option value="">-- Select --</option>                              
                            <dblookup:DBLookupTagVer2 lookUpName="common.spotter.outletd" >

                            </dblookup:DBLookupTagVer2>

                            </html:select>

                <%
                }
                 %>

                        </td>
            </tr>
```

So as u can see I used Scriplets to instantiate the form and use its attributes, as already saved my current form's values and called the JS method in the Base Dorp down input, so when I will change the Base value all the forms values will be repopulated and then my outlet will have access to the new Base value and based on that it will loat the suitable query refering to these QueryTags :

```
<query cacheDuration="90000" cacheMaxRows="100" key="common.spotter.outletb" toCache="true">
    <stmt>
    <![CDATA[
    SELECT BIBRCD, BIBRCD||'-'||BIBRNM from e31dlib3.GBRANCH where BIBRTY='B' AND BIRS='A'
    ]]>
    </stmt>
</query>
<query cacheDuration="90000" cacheMaxRows="100" key="common.spotter.outletd" toCache="true">
    <stmt>
    <![CDATA[
    SELECT BIBRCD, BIBRCD||'-'||BIBRNM from e31dlib3.GBRANCH where BIBRTY='D' AND BIRS='A'
    ]]>
    </stmt>
</query>
```

That's all, all is done and it works perfectly for me, if not enough details lemme know !